# Изменить позицию фигуры в SVG

Tags: css3, html5, svg, css-animation

Как перемещать фигуры?
x и y работает только в circle (или может других), а мне нужно либо в polygon, либо в path.
Там x и y не работают. Именно переместить на странице, у меня фигуры всегда в верхнем углу.
HTML:

```
    <div id="mapa" class="dragger">
    </div>
        <svg id="_mapa" class="dragger" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path stroke="lightseagreen" stroke-width="5" fill="turquoise"
                d="M 20,20 h 160 v 160 h -80 v -80 h -80 z"/>
    </svg>
```

CSS:

```
#mapa {
position: relative;
width: 6000px;
height: 6000px;
overflow: hidden;
background: url('../img/map.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size: 6000px 6000px;
}

#_mapa {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 6000px;
height: 6000px;
overflow: hidden;
background-size: 6000px 6000px;
pointer-events: visibleFill;
```

}

Comment: код хотя бы показал бы

Comment: Добавил код....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

может поэтому они всегда слева в углу..?

Comment: Тогда фигуры выходят за картинку, а мне нужно рисовать их именно на этой картинке.

Comment: @MaxFranko  ?? https://jsfiddle.net/zy6oybrL/

Comment: @MaxFranko бывает..))))

Comment: Не то, он меняет позицию самого svg (следовательно эту фигуру тоже), а у меня будет много фигур и у каждой своя позиция на картинке.

Comment: так задайте каждой фегуре свою позицию при создании... просто не  надо задавать им размеры 6000px

Comment: да я уже туплю тут под ночь, разобрался, спасибо!

Comment: @Pit Pit Приветствую Вас на stackoverflow/ Вы задали свой вопрос в посте ответа, поэтому модератор видимо преобразует его в комментарий. Задайте свой вопрос в новом топике. Здесь я уже дал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1113289/28748) до удаления вашего вопроса В новом вашем вопросе я дам более подробный ответ, как это всё делается

Answer (score 3):

Фигуры SVG можно передвигать командами трансформации

**Внутри SVG**

`transform="translate(100,100)"`

**Правилами CSS**

`transform:translate(100px,100px);`

Обратите внимание, что в CSS нужно указывать пиксели

*Ниже пример анимации CSS перемещения фигуры при наведении курсора:*

```css
.dragger {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
}

#mapa path {
transition: transform 1s linear; 
}
#mapa:hover path {
transform:translate(100px,100px);
}
```

```html
<div  class="dragger">
   
        <svg id="mapa" viewBox="0 0 300 300"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path stroke="lightseagreen" stroke-width="5" fill="turquoise"
                d="M 20,20 h 160 v 160 h -80 v -80 h -80 z"/>
    </svg>
 </div>
```

Comment: у кого-то бессонница ?

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ на вопрос @Pit Pit**

В этом примере стрелку будем перемещать по вертикали:

```
transform:translate(0px,200px);
```

```css
.dragger {
width: 25%;
height: 25%;
}

#mapa path {
transition: transform 1s linear; 
}
#mapa:hover path {
transform:translate(0px,600px);
}
```

```html
<div  class="dragger">
   
        <svg id="mapa" viewBox="0 0 600 600"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path id="p1" stroke="lightseagreen" stroke-width="5" fill="turquoise"
                d="M442.627,185.388L265.083,7.844C260.019,2.78,253.263,0,245.915,0c-7.204,0-13.956,2.78-19.02,7.844L49.347,185.388
        c-10.488,10.492-10.488,27.568,0,38.052l16.12,16.128c5.064,5.06,11.82,7.844,19.028,7.844c7.204,0,14.192-2.784,19.252-7.844
        l103.808-103.584v329.084c0,14.832,11.616,26.932,26.448,26.932h22.8c14.832,0,27.624-12.1,27.624-26.932V134.816l104.396,104.752
        c5.06,5.06,11.636,7.844,18.844,7.844s13.864-2.784,18.932-7.844l16.072-16.128C453.163,212.952,453.123,195.88,442.627,185.388z"/>
    </svg>
 </div>
```

Comment: _на вопрос @ Pit Pit_ - это пока ещё  "ответ". На нём тревога ещё не обработана, он будет преобразован в комментарий. Добавте пожалуйста после того в ответ ссылку на комментарий.

Comment: @0xdb Видимо завтра, после обработки тревоги, укажу ссылку

Comment: Саша здаровеньки былы !

Comment: @MaximLensky Привет! Что случилось, почему на Украинский перешел с Казахского :)

Comment: изучаю - я там с тостера затянул человека - поможешь ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1113322/308951

Comment: @MaximLensky помогу, если смогу, только не сейчас, немного погодя