# Не работает transition в Chrome при :hover на многоцветных иконках, стили которых заданы CSS переменными

Tags: css, svg

Есть svg иконка которая вставляется с помощью `<use>`. Необходимо добиться плавности перехода от одних цветов к другим при `:hover`. Иконка состоит из нескольких элементов и каждый должен менять цвет на какой-то свой определенный поэтому здесь не подойдет конструкция в css вида

```
svg { fill: #ddd; transition: .25s; }
svg:hover { fill: #ddd; }
```

Минимальный пример реализован ниже.
p.s. если проверять с FF то все работает, но в chrome и opera беда

```css
:root {
  --color: #33d;
  --color-bg: #99b;
}

svg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

circle, path {
  transition: 0.25s;
}

svg:hover {
  --color: #d33;
  --color-bg: #d99;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: none;">
  <svg id="play" viewBox="0 0 22 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="11" cy="11" r="11" fill="var(--color)"/>
    <circle cx="11.0001" cy="11.0001" r="9.9" fill="var(--color-bg)"/>
    <path d="M8.7998 13.4619V8.4001C8.7998 7.61556 9.66199 7.13657 10.3281 7.55104L14.1245 9.91323C14.7308 10.2905 14.7577 11.1634 14.1757 11.5772L10.3793 14.2769C9.71725 14.7477 8.7998 14.2743 8.7998 13.4619Z" fill="var(--color)"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#play"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: так как мне цвет использовать если у меня несколько элементов и у каждого свой цвет. т.е. не могу я просто взять и написать `svg { fill: #234432; }`. Буду думать..., может напишу какое нибудь локально расширение которое будет искать нужный тег и вставлять туда разметку svg, а не use

Comment: Не понял вас, можно пример? как обрабатывать :hover тогда?

Comment: выше пример же - в codepen.io

Comment: так а если у меня несколько circle как в моем примере? к тому же ваш пример не совпадает с моим, у меня используется use и как раз таки в нем основная загвоздка, то что через него transition не прокидывается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что это действительно проблема `Chrome`, когда он обрабатывает переменные  в `<use>` 
Пробовал различные варианты и комбинации, но `transition` с переменными не работает

Убрал `<use>`, окружности и `path` обернул в групповой тег `<g id="play">` и в chrome заработало.

```css
:root {
  --color: #33d;
  --color-bg: #99b;
}

svg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

circle, path {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#play:hover {
  --color: #d33;
  --color-bg: #d99;
}
```

```html
<div >
  <svg  viewBox="0 0 22 22"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="play">
 <circle cx="11" cy="11" r="11" fill="var(--color)"/>
    <circle cx="11.0001" cy="11.0001" r="9.9" fill="var(--color-bg)"/>
    <path d="M8.7998 13.4619V8.4001C8.7998 7.61556 9.66199 7.13657 10.3281 7.55104L14.1245 9.91323C14.7308 10.2905 14.7577 11.1634 14.1757 11.5772L10.3793 14.2769C9.71725 14.7477 8.7998 14.2743 8.7998 13.4619Z" fill="var(--color)"/>
 </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Ниже пример с трехцветной иконкой**

```css
 :root {
  --tr:1s;
  }
 #cup {
  --color-1: #c13127;
  --color-2: #ef5b49;
  --color-3: #cacaea;
 
 }

  #cup:hover {
 --color-1: gold;
  --color-2: skyblue;
  --color-3: yellowgreen;
   
 }
 rect, path {
 transition: var(--tr);
{
```

```html
 <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"  viewBox="0 0 20 20" >
       
  <g id="cup">   
    <path   fill="var(--color-1)"   d="M15,17H14V9h3a3,3,0,0,1,3,3h0A5,5,0,0,1,15,17Zm1-6v3.83A3,3,0,0,0,18,12a1,1,0,0,0-1-1Z"/>
    <rect  fill="var(--color-2)" x="1" y="7" width="15" height="12" rx="3" ry="3"/>
    <path  fill="var(--color-3)"  d="M7.07,5.42a5.45,5.45,0,0,1,0-4.85,1,1,0,0,1,1.79.89,3.44,3.44,0,0,0,0,3.06,1,1,0,0,1-1.79.89Z"/>
    <path  fill="var(--color-3)" d="M3.07,5.42a5.45,5.45,0,0,1,0-4.85,1,1,0,0,1,1.79.89,3.44,3.44,0,0,0,0,3.06,1,1,0,1,1-1.79.89Z"/>
    <path  fill="var(--color-3)" d="M11.07,5.42a5.45,5.45,0,0,1,0-4.85,1,1,0,0,1,1.79.89,3.44,3.44,0,0,0,0,3.06,1,1,0,1,1-1.79.89Z"/>
   </g>
   
  
</svg>
```

Comment: правильно ли я вас понял что в таком случае не нужно использовать use, а вставлять прямиком svg по ходу верстки? значит на js напишу кусочек кода, который будет менять use на его содержимое.

Comment: @Алексей Да, именно так. Очень похоже, что это баг Chrome.  Я потратил значительное время на поиски решения, перечитал теорию, должно работать с `use`, но не работает Вот хорошая статья - [Делаем разноцветные иконки с помощью SVG-символов и CSS-переменных](https://habr.com/ru/post/348194/)

Comment: Статья полезная, более подробная чем я видел, спасибо. Будем надеяться, что когда-нибудь это заработает, а пока будем городить. Еще бы анимацию градиентов завезли когда-нибудь, но это уже совсем другая тема.

Comment: @Алексей Благодарю. А не хотите задать отдельный вопрос по анимации градиентов? Это действительно интересный вопрос. Я его изучал именно в разрезе кроссбраузерности

Comment: @Алексей я это объяснял что не кроссбраузерное использовать use для этого

Comment: я так понял что просто надо дублировать инлайновым способом svg а fill stroke указывать можно через переменные ?

Comment: @MaximLensky в примерах выше нет дублирования SVG/ Стили иконок меняются переменными. Так как переменные имеют наивысший приоритет (вычисляемый стиль) перед другими способами стилизации.

Comment: ну а если к примеру надо 5 стаканов с разными цветами сделать ?

Comment: @MaximLensky если без `transition` вместе с переменными,  то use работает и с переменными, выше ссылка на статью. А в комбинации параметров, которые были в вопросе `use`+`var` +`transition` не работает,  это похоже баг Chrome

Comment: тогда ваще var 100 лет не нужен...